# Additional Column will not commit to table created in previous migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-core-2.0

I created a table with these columns in it initially.

I have the following class which is already been created by migrations in the database.

```
public class Products
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public string ShotDescription { get; set; }

    public decimal OldPrice { get; set; }

    public decimal NewPrice { get; set; }

    public bool DisableBuyButton { get; set; }

    public bool DisableWishListButton { get; set; }

    public bool ShowForPrice { get; set; }


    public bool NotReturnable { get; set; }

    public int MinimumCartQty { get; set; }

    public int MaximumCartQty { get; set; }

    public string SKU { get; set; }


    public bool ShippingEnabled { get; set; }

    public decimal Weight { get; set; }

    public decimal Length { get; set; }

    public decimal Width { get; set; }

    public decimal Height { get; set; }

    public string Categories { get; set; }

    public string ManufacturerPartNumber        { get; set; }

    public DateTime AvailableDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime AvailableEndDate { get; set; }

    public string AdminComment { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }


    public Boolean DisplayAvailability { get; set; }

    public DateTime ExpectedDateBackOnStock { get; set; }

    public bool IsOnBackOrder { get; set; }

    public int Warehouse { get; set; }

    public int BinNumber { get; set; }

    public int IlseNumber { get; set; }



    public bool IsGiftCard { get; set; }

    public bool IsDownloadableProduct { get; set; }

    public bool IsRental { get; set; }


    public string SeoDescription { get; set; }


    public int   Stock { get; set; }

    public int PropertyImageId { get; set; }
```

}

I used the following command to create the migrations and then update the database.

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate

Update-Database
```

However when I come to add a new column to it it will not commit the user id column to the table even though it is now in the new class it produces no errors and just says Done in the Package Management Console But it has not added the column into the table on the database. Can someone advice me as to what I may be doing wrong thanks. The field in question is

> public Guid UserId { get; set; }

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Text;

namespace solitude.models.Models
{
    public class Products
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        public string ShotDescription { get; set; }

        public decimal OldPrice { get; set; }

        public decimal NewPrice { get; set; }

        public bool DisableBuyButton { get; set; }

        public bool DisableWishListButton { get; set; }

        public bool ShowForPrice { get; set; }


        public bool NotReturnable { get; set; }

        public int MinimumCartQty { get; set; }

        public int MaximumCartQty { get; set; }

        public string SKU { get; set; }


        public bool ShippingEnabled { get; set; }

        public decimal Weight { get; set; }

        public decimal Length { get; set; }

        public decimal Width { get; set; }

        public decimal Height { get; set; }

        public string Categories { get; set; }

        public string ManufacturerPartNumber        { get; set; }

        public DateTime AvailableDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime AvailableEndDate { get; set; }

        public string AdminComment { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

        public DateTime UpdatedOn { get; set; }


        public Boolean DisplayAvailability { get; set; }

        public DateTime ExpectedDateBackOnStock { get; set; }

        public bool IsOnBackOrder { get; set; }

        public int Warehouse { get; set; }

        public int BinNumber { get; set; }

        public int IlseNumber { get; set; }



        public bool IsGiftCard { get; set; }

        public bool IsDownloadableProduct { get; set; }

        public bool IsRental { get; set; }


        public string SeoDescription { get; set; }


        public int   Stock { get; set; }

        public int PropertyImageId { get; set; }


        public Guid UserId { get; set; }  


    }
}
```

Comment: "it will not commit it to the table" Please elaborate on that. Where/when/how should anything be committed (code)? Any exceptions? Was the database actually modified?

Comment: @GertArnold revised the question there

Comment: "it says Done", By that do you mean in Package Manager Console when you do another update on the database?

Comment: @Jared that is correct in the package manager console but yet when I look at the table the column has not been added I edited the question further to add that.

Comment: EF Core does not support automatic migrations like EF6. Hence after modifying the model (like adding a column etc.), you need to create new migration, e.g. `Add-Migration Migration2` and *then* do `Update-Database`.